# Convert general date format

Tags: c#

my problem is 
`Fri May 06 2016 06:00:00 GMT+0600 (Azores Standard Time)`

i need datetime format as like `05/06/2016 06:10 pm (MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm T)`

Comment: `date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm T")`

Comment: Cmon man, did you try looking for a solution before asking?  Date format code is everywhere...

Answer (score 0):

If you trim the "GMT+0600 (Azores Standard Time)" off the full date/time string you can use DateTime.Parse to parse to a DateTime object and then convert to any string format you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string dateAsString = "Fri May 06 2016 06:00:00 GMT+0600";
dateAsString = dateAsString.Substring(0, dateAsString.IndexOf("GMT")).Trim();
string nowDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss");
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateAsString, "ddd MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var result = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us");
string date = "Fri May 06 2016 06:00:00 GMT+0600 (Azores Standard Time)";
DateTime DT = DateTime.Parse(date.Split('G')[0]);
string value = DT.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt", ci);
MessageBox.Show(value);
```

Comment: thanks for your solution,Specially datetime parse system is nice ,I learnt new think.thank u so much